# Вызов метода android

Tags: java, android

Есть метод: discoverDevices(View view)

code:

```
     public class SearchActivity extends Activity {


private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
private BroadcastReceiver discoverDevicesReceiver;
private BroadcastReceiver discoveryFinishedReceiver;


private final List<BluetoothDevice> discoveredDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

private final List<String> discoveredD = new ArrayList<>();


private ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> listAdapter;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


}


public void discoverDevices(View view) {

    discoveredDevices.clear();
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    if (discoverDevicesReceiver == null) {
        discoverDevicesReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();

                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    if (!discoveredDevices.contains(device)) {
                        discoveredDevices.add(device);
                        discoveredD.add(device.getName());
                        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    if (discoveryFinishedReceiver == null) {
        discoveryFinishedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {


            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                if (progressDialog != null)
                    progressDialog.dismiss();


                final JSONArray Codes = new JSONArray(discoveredD);


                intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, SearchActivity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("codes", Codes.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
                unregisterReceiver(discoveryFinishedReceiver);
            }

        };

    }


    registerReceiver(discoverDevicesReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
    registerReceiver(discoveryFinishedReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED));


    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, getString(R.string.search_bt), getString(R.string.wait));

    bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    if (discoverDevicesReceiver != null) {
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(discoverDevicesReceiver);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("SearchActivity", "Error turn off reciever: " + discoverDevicesReceiver);
        }
    }


}

 }
```

Мне нужно вызвать метод `discoverDevices()` при старте активити (раньше вызывался при нажатии на кнопку). Как вызвать?

> log:
>
> 09-24 22:56:21.475  12493-12493/com.totalsx.ltmE/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.totalsx.ltm/com.totalsx.ltm.SearchActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.totalsx.ltm.SearchActivity.discoverDevices(SearchActivity.java:203)
>               at com.totalsx.ltm.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:195)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените

```
public void test (View view) {
// SOME
}
```

на

```
public void test (View view) {
    test();
}
public void test () {
// SOME
}
```

У вас метод с параметром, в который раньше передавалась View, на которую клацали, теперь вы метод сами вызываете.

### UPD

Я не увидел, что у вас listAdapter где-то инициализируется, но вы активно к нему обращаетесь. Хотелось бы увидеть стек трейс ошибки.

Comment: Теперь после запуска активити в логах: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: потому, что вы оставили этот метод как обработчик какой-то кнопки?! Посмотрите мой ответ заново, я исправил, я думаю, что вы оставили метод тест привязанным к какой-то кнопке.

Comment: да, раньше через android:onClick="test" вызывал метод,  теперь надо при запуске активити вызвать test

Comment: Так же ошибка FATAL EXCEPTION

Comment: обновил вопрос, добавил код полностью

Comment: @IlyaNenilin, читайте ответ.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: Убрал listAdapter вообще из кода все заработало.  Перестало только передавать Codes. Как здесь быть? Ошибок нет перестал данные передавать

Comment: Прошу прощения все работает.  Спасибо!

Comment: @IlyaNenilin, рад, что помог)

Answer (score 1):

Поместите его в метод onCreate() активити

Comment: Я пишу в oncreate(): test (). Он мне ошибкой подчеркивает

Comment: Какую ошибку пишет? Метод в классе активити определён? Вы аргумент в него передали?

Comment: test (View) in Activity cannot be applied to ()